# How can I change the dpi of an image in PythonMagick?

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick

I am using images for ocr and I need to change the dpi as part of pre-processing.

```
import PythonMagick

img_file = 'my_image.jpg'
img = PythonMagick.Image(file)
img.density("600") # It does not seem to work
img.write(img_file + '.tif')
```

I could call ImageMagick but I would rather use PythonMagick.

Comment: Setting DPI density in command line usualy goes with ```-units PixelsPerInch``` option. Sorry don't know the PythonMagick equivalent

Comment: I use the following but it does not work:
convert my_image.jpg -density 600 -units PixelsPerInch my_image.tif

Comment: you have wrong order of options. try this ```convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 1200x1200 input.jpg ouput.tif```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem.
With help form other blogs and sites, i came up with a solution.

```
import PythonMagick

img_file = 'my_image.jpg'
img = PythonMagick.Image()
img.density("600")
img.read(file) #read it at 600 dpi
img.write(img_file + '.tif')
```

The problem here is to read it at 600dpi before writing it.
This should work.